# jQuery - On Hover of div, slide in div and be able to hover over the newly opened div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-hover

I'm trying to do hover over bottom bar, which will slide in another div just above it which I can click items located within on and then when i mouse off both the "appeared div" will slide away.

However, when I move my mouse from the bottom bar to click on something in the newly appeared div (slid in div) it re-enabled the effect, how can I stop this so I can hover over both (after the slid in div is enabled) and have it how restart the effect essentially placing it into a loop of the same slideDown/slideUp effect.

Here's my code:

```
$(".playlist").hide();
$(".player, .playlist").hover( 
    function(){ $(".playlist").slideDown(); },
    function(){ $(".playlist").slideUp(); }
);
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="playlist">
<!-- This would display some content that I can click on -->
</div>

<div class="player">
<!-- This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you place what you have in a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jv25Y/

**New Markup**

```
<div class="player">
    <div class="playlist">
         This would display some content that I can click on 
    </div>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom
</div>
```

**New JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(".playlist").hide();
    $(".player").hover( 
        function(){ $(".playlist").slideDown(); },
        function(){ $(".playlist").slideUp(); }
    );
});
```

Would something like that work? Basically playlist is contained in player now. So your mouse will not leave player, when you are trying to click a link in playlist. If that doesnt quite fit (due to styling on your page etc) You can also just wrap an element around playlist and player and then call hover on it instead like this,

**Markup**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="playlist">
         This would display some content that I can click on 
    </div>
    <div class="player">
        This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#wrapper").hover( 
     function(){ $(".playlist").slideDown(); },
     function(){ $(".playlist").slideUp(); }
 );
```